# How to use ilMerge to merge dll into an exe file?

Tags: dll, merge, cmd, exe, ilmerge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Merging .dll with .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551311/merging-dll-with-exe)

Okay, so... I have all the files of ilmerge, along with the .exe (CabalMain.exe) and the dll (crckd.dll) in one path. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge`

I shift>rightclick folder and open up command prompt.
Since I'd like to merge the two I enter:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerg
e\ilmerge C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\Cabalmain.exe C:\Program File
s (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\crckd.dll /out:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerg
e
```

(I believe that is the correct process to merge)
And I received

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerg
e\ilmerge C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\Cabalmain.exe C:\Program File
s (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\crckd.dll /out:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerg
e
```

Simple instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have seen this question (and an answer or comment on it) before today. What happened?

Comment: Yes it's a popular injection that came out today. I just need to know, or i would like to know rather, how to inject .dll into .exe, and if my strategy is correct.

Answer (score 5):

As you have now copied every thing in the programs folder of ilmerge (which is not wise and was adviced against in the duplicate question) the correct command (from the ilmerge folder) should be:

```
ilmerge cabalmain.exe crckd.dll /out:%userprofile%\cabalmainmerged.exe
```

If no errors are shown you can type `start %userprofile%` and in the explorer window that opens you should find cabalmainmerged.exe

'Could not load assembly ' means that the exe or dll files that you try to merge are not copied to the correct folder. If one of the exe or dll's depend on other assemblys they all have to be in the same folder.

Wiser is to have a folder c:\merge and copy all relevant files in that folder. Then start a commandprompt and

> c:
>
> cd\merge

then

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ilmerge" "yourexe.exe" "your1stdll.dll" /out:mergedexe.exe
```

Comment: Rene, this happened.
An exception occurred during merging:
ILMerge.Merge: Could not load assembly from t
\Microsoft\ILMerge\cabalmain.exe'. Skipping a
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)

Comment: You are pretty sure cabalmain.exe is in the same folder as ilmerge?

Comment: http://imgur.com/jgYTVdf

 Yes, as you can see they all are Q_Q.

Comment: It seems you are out of luck then. cabalmain.exe is probably depending on another dll you don't have.