# combine files to c# exe

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am currently creating a c# application
with `sqlite db`

to run it I need the `sqlite dll` files the data base file
cant I add them to the `exe` file so that it can be in 1 file instead of 5?

Comment: use ilmerge in postbuild to get dll's and exe togetther:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551556/how-to-use-ilmerge-to-merge-dll-into-an-exe-file

Comment: Typing question title into google, [second](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10137937/1997232) result.